# How can I play a local stored mp4-video on Android with phonegap (HTML5/Javascript)?

Tags: android, video, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an App with Phonegap and I can't play a local stored (in camera folder) video within my App. I found http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.de/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html but it doesn't work out for me the app just keeps showing my index.html page. If I just do it like in the instructions there are also errors that the VideoPlayer.java file can't import from "org.apache.cordova.api" which is not automatically in the "libs" folder so I copied "cordova-2.9.0.jar" in it and at least the errors disappear.

I also found broken-links.com/tests/video/ and it works well in the standard-browser but if I use the html and javascript files and put them in my assets/www folder in the app it doesn' work. It just keeps showing the video element without the video in it.

The video needs to be stored local so the app works offline.

Is there maybe a way to copy a video from the DCIM folder into a folder in a directory in my .apk package?

Or do you have a working project which plays a local stored video (mp4), so I can compare?

Comment: if u get any answer please share the code i m also getting same problem and have no clue that how to do everytime getting new errors on adding plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it's working if I delete the import of the PhoneGap-JavaScript

`<script src="phonegap.js"></script>`

on the HTML page I'm using the video tag. A bit weird but apparently PhoneGap blocks it in some way.

For this solution I didn't copy the video anywhere nor used any kind of framework.
I just used .mp4 videos so I have no idea how it is with other formats.